# Як перекласти українською "подходящий"?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, дієприкметники

Потрібний точний семантичний еквівалент, не можу його пригадати.

Приклад використання:

"К сожалению, по вашему запросу не найдено **подходящих** компаний".

Glosbe дає [велику кількість варіантів](https://glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9), але, як можна переконатися, потрібного для цієї ситуації серед них немає. Буду вдячний шановній спільноті за підказку.

**update**

Дам деяке уточнення ситуації з огляду на коментарі. Є повна база компаній України (ЄДРПОУ). Для деяких з цих компаній можна замовити певний сервіс (скажімо, фінансовий аналіз), а для інших — технічно неможливо.

Користувач од початку не знає, чи можливий цей сервіс для тієї компанії, що його цікавить. Він вводить код ЄДРПОУ. І отут ми маємо дати людині зрозуміти, що компанія в базі є (інакше вона вважатиме, що база в нас неповна, адже точно знає, що код компанії дійсний), але, як пошуковий результат для даного конкретного сервісу, вона непридатна.

Справа навіть не в тому, щоб підібрати рішення з точку зору користувацького досвіду. Таке рішення знайдемо. Цікавинка в тому, щоб підібрати належний до цього випадку український відповідник.

Поки що схиляюся до думки, що влучніш за все будуть "належний" і "придатний", але вони все ще не є точними семантичними відповідниками.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ми вирішили зупинитися на слові "**підхожий**" з таких причин:

- воно є в лексикографічних джерелах ([СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkhozhyj)) і має саме таке значення як потрібне;
- воно є інтуїтивно зрозумілим для тих, хто не володіє українською, бо перекликається з "подходящий"
- воно не є дієприкметником (як "підходящий"), які не властиві українській мові в цілому, і звучить цілком природньо в мовному плині.

Також маю зазначити, що мені нагадали про слова що мають дуже близьке значення до потрібного:

- належний
- доречний
- придатний

Comment: Дієприкметникофобія — хвороба, від якої треба лікуватися насправді. Нічого, крім окремої думки окремих мовознавців-пуристів, за нею не стоїть.

Comment: Хоча, з іншого боку, «підходящий», ймовірно, було запозичено з російської (закономірний український дієприкметник — підхо́дячий). «Підхожий», попри підтвердженість джерелами, слово маловживане, не пасує стилістично до технічного тексту. Як на мене, «придатний» чи «відповідний» (залежно від контексту) — оптимальний варіант.

Answer (score 4):

Стаття 46 Закону України "Про зайнятість населення" [використовує](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/5067-17) слово "підходяща", хоча це слово може здатися суржиком. Це слово [присутнє](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkhodjashhyj) в СУМ.

Щодо фрази, можна й уникати цього слова, проте якщо вживати й це слово. Можна сказати, що потрібних компаній не знайдено, або ж "жодної компанії не знайдено".

Comment: Дякую за посилання на СУМ. Завдяки йому довідався, що слово "підхожий" все ж таки є в словнику, має потрібні значення і є найбільш придатним до моєї ситуації!

Comment: Деякі [словники](//uk.worldwidedictionary.org/підходящий) все таки вважають «підходящий» розмовним, хоча в авторитетних я поки що такої позначки біля цього слова не бачив.

Answer (score 4):

До слова “подходящий” підходять слова:

- Відповідний
- Подібний
- Схожий

Я схиляюсь до перекладу - "Відповідний"

[Посилання на джерело](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidpovidnyj)

Answer (score 3):

До «[підхожий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidkhozhyj)», «[придатний](http://sum.in.ua/s/prydatnyj)» є ще такі **не зовсім нормативні** синоніми:

- [годя́щий](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghodjashhyj) ([∗](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19045&page=650)) — розм.;
- [го́жий](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghozhyj) ([∗](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=19050&page=650)) — розм.;
- [догі́дний](http://sum.in.ua/s/doghidnyj) ([∗](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23213&page=786)) — діал.;
- нагі́дний — лише в старих словниках ([1933](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&scope=ukr&dicts=1&highlight=on));
- [пригі́дний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryghidnyj) — розм. рідко;
- [приго́жий](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryghozhyj) — розм.

∗ — посилання на нову версію словника (містить лише А–КВАРТА).

Comment: Думаю, що усі слова, що містяться у цій відповіді, не підходять, бо вони розмовні, а автор прямо написав, що йдеться про офіційний сайт ЄДРПОУ (Єдиного *Державного Реєстру*…)

Comment: @bytebuster, не впевнений, що мова йдеться про офіційний сайт ЄДРПОУ. Автор лише написав, що пошук відбувається за ЄДРПОУ. Чи сайт комерційний, чи державний, чи інший — на 100% не відомо.

Comment: Сайт комерційний, але стиль мови офіційний.

Comment: Ну, оскільки в питанні зараз не зазначено, що лише офіційні, а у відповіді є попередження «не зовсім нормативні» (і пояснення чому), то я все ж поки не буду прибирати. Раптом знадобиться іншому читачу. Тим більше, що з часу видання СУМ-11 минуло 36–46 років і деякі (хоч і, мабуть, менш авторитетні за СУМ) словники дають [деякі](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=догідний&dicts=5&main_only=on) з цих слів без усіляких поміт і «Мова. ДНК нації рекомендує [деякі](//ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/yak-pereklastu-ukrayinskoyu-podxodyashhuj) з них замість нормативного у СУМ «підходящий».

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine "нагідний" не розмовне.

Answer (score -1):

Суто українське слово, що відповідає саме такому значенню — нагідний.

Comment: Цей допис не додає нічого нового порівняно з [однією з наявних відповідей](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1063/8). Якщо ви мали на увазі розгорнути відповідь стосовно одного конкретного слова, надати більш детальні пояснення і більшу кількість поважних джерел, ніж у попередній відповіді, то має сенс робити це зараз. Якщо ж ви, натомість, бажаєте лише підтвердити сказане у тій відповіді, для цього є кнопка upvote, і це не потребує створення відповідей-дублікатів.